# Dependency injection fails for a third-party bundle

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony4

When I run the following code (standard dependency injection):

```
use Khill\Lavacharts\Lavacharts;

class MainController extends AbstractController {

  protected $lavacharts;

  function __construct(Lavacharts $lavacharts) {
    $this->lavacharts = $lavacharts;
  }
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot autowire service "DefaultController": 
argument "$lavacharts" of method "MainController::__construct()" 
references class "Khill\Lavacharts\Lavacharts" but no such 
service exists. You should maybe alias this class to the 
existing "lavacharts" service
```

So I added an alias to the lavachart service in my `services.yml`, which is a vendor bundle, like this:

```
Khill\Lavacharts\Lavacharts\: "@lavacharts"
```

This is how the `lavacharts` service is defined by the vendor:

```
parameters:
    khill.lavacharts.class: Khill\Lavacharts\Lavacharts
    khill.lavacharts.twig: Khill\Lavacharts\Symfony\Bundle\Twig\LavachartsExtension

services:
    lavacharts:
        class: "%khill.lavacharts.class%"

    lavacharts.twig_extension:
        class: "%khill.lavacharts.twig%"
        public: false
        arguments: ['@lavacharts']
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

But this is not working, and I keep getting the same error although I have the feeling that I created the expected alias (based on [the official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#service-autowiring-alias)). What am i missing?

Comment: You can debug the container with the help of symfony console commands:

`./bin/console debug:container`

see If you can find the class added. when not there is an error in your service.yaml

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did it and can correctly see the lavacharts service : `lavacharts Khill\Lavacharts\Lavacharts`

Answer (score 0):

Ah! OK I found it myself.

In the service declaration, the trailing backslash should be omitted (I didn't understand why exactly yet) :

`Khill\Lavacharts\Lavacharts: "@lavacharts"`

and NOT

`Khill\Lavacharts\Lavacharts\: "@lavacharts"`

(note the trailing backslash difference)